# How can I repack JPEG?

Tags: jpeg

I have some JPEG files uploaded by users. I need to be sure they are "clean". Sure, I can just recompress them to JPEG again and I will get "clean" files but either I will loose quality or files will be bigger.

So how can I repack JPEG files? I mean how can I loslessy copy "body" of the compressed JPEG but strip anything else (all comments, EXIF, zero bytes appended to files etc.)? I have seen some JPEG files with ZIP files appended to them. People use them to post as a JPEG but then they download, unpack the ZIP and have some special content hidden from site moderators. I want to avoid that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `jpegtran -copy none -optimize` for that.

Comment: You beat me to it! But yes, jpegtran is a life-saver.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. There is, however, one thing that bothers me. I tried repacking some jpegs with it and same of them became bigger AFTER jpegtran.

Comment: @Tom Sometimes, `-progessive` result in smaller files than `-optimize`.

Comment: @user2233709 progressive JPEGs however don't work well with lepton and guetzli, which may not appear like a problem but the developers of those projects also brought up that progressive doesn't work well on mobile devices. Just a heads up.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Just curious, what are “lepton and guetzli”?

Comment: @user2233709 https://github.com/dropbox/lepton a tool dropbox developed to store JPEGs more efficiently in their data centers, quite useful if you want to backup a large amount of JPEGs and want to reduce the file size of the backup by ~10-20%, back and forth conversion also helps identifying broken files (you won't be able to convert them, but you know which one are broken then) https://github.com/google/guetzli the latest released research project from Google in the line of zopfli and brotli trying to improve a particular compression technology (or inventing a new one)

Comment: @LiveWireBT Thanks for pointing these. Aren’t they better options than my suggested `jpegtran`? Should’t you propose them in a answer?

Comment: @user2233709 Lepton is not compatible with JPEG decoders or any other well known image decoder (Dropbox does decoding on the fly on their end). guetzli, like zopfli and brotli, require a lot of CPU resources and is rather slow, you can use it – I do – especially when preparing content from lossless source to lossy for web publishing, but it's not a good choice for instant content checking as requested here. Hope that clears it up. :)

Comment: @ser2233709 Yes, that's it! Original file is 26.8 kB. With -optimize it becomes 27.1 kB but with -progressive it's 26.6 kB. I hate how progressive images load on a website (you never know if they are 100% loaded or still missing a few bytes) so I am not going to use that option. Just wanted to be sure that jpegtran is really as good as it gets. Thanks again!

Comment: @LiveWireBT I heard about Guetzli, Brotli and Zopfli but never about Lepton. Seems like a handy thing for archiving. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Tom Just curious, was your original file also progressive-encoded?

Comment: @user2233709 Honestly, I have no idea how to check it. My guess is it was.

Comment: @Tom I thought it should be feasible, but I honestly don’t know either how to check it.